# Import a public C enumeration from a C library into kotlin project

Tags: java, android, c, android-studio, kotlin

We are working on a `C` library and trying to consume it on an Android `kotlin` project.
Everything works fine except for `enum` declared in the library itself.
It seems that cases defined are not available.
We had the same issue on `Swift` but we were able to takle it by conditional compiling the library and adding a specific attribute in the `C` code. Here a sample .h that once consumed by swift compiler can show the correct number of enum cases instead of just the `uint32_t` raw value.

```
#if defined (__APPLE__)
#include <CoreFoundation/CFAvailability.h>

typedef CF_ENUM(uint32_t, Cases) {
  case_zero         = 0,
  case_one          = 1
};
#else
typedef enum {
  case_zero         = 0,
  case_one          = 1
} Cases;
#endif
```

Is there any way to mark the enumeration to make it visible with all cases also on a `kotlin`(or maybe `java`) project without the need of rewriting a remapping?

Comment: What does the apparent macro `CF_ENUM` expand to?

Comment: @thebusybee into something like that available in Clang  `__attribute__((enum_extensibility(open)))`

Comment: Please show the preprocessor's output in your question.

Comment: I have to ask, I'm not the one building the library, but to avoid any missunderstanding about the question. The CF_ENUM is used only on Swift side and it solves the issue. What I'am looking for is a similar solution on kotlin side, that is the `else` of the `C` code posted.

Comment: So you are saying that the shown source can be included in a Swift source or translated as Swift? I thought it is C, and therefore I asked for the expanded source (look up the `-E` option of GCC and Clang). As I understand it, you need to add _something_ to make the compiler export more than the usual stuff, so that the linker knows how to resolve the references. Commonly the names of enumerated constants are gone and replaced by their numeric values after compiling.

Comment: @thebusybee basically yes, the part wrapped in the check for `__APPLE__` when we consume the library exposes a full enum with all labeled cases instead of just a class with a raw `Int` value.
The question is about ,is there something similar also on kotlin side? a defined macro that can make us able to export the full enumeration, without the need of remapping it?

Comment: Hm, I think we are talking past each other. My core issue is: Is the presented source snippet really read by a Swift compiler? A quick research seems to show that `typedef` is not a Swift keyword, so I asked for confirmation. -- The term "_consume the library_" is a bit unclear to me. Does building a Swift application work similarly to building a C application? Then it means what, reading and compiling the source code, or linking against the compiled C library? At least in the C world, these are two distinct processes.

Comment: Anyway, as Swift seems to be "near enough" to C, the source could be accepted by a Swift preprocessor and compiler. Couldn't you expand it with another `#elif` and filter it through, for example, the C or Swift preprocessor before giving it to the Kotlin compiler? A quick web search revelaed no preprocessor for Kotlin.